# Processing Sketch not working on JavaScript mode

Tags: javascript, java, html, processing, processing.js

I use Processing 2.2.1
I have created a very simple app just to test the JavaScript mode:

```
void setup()
{
  size(300,300);
  smooth();
  background(0);
}

void draw()
{
  noStroke();
  fill(random(0,255), random(0,255), random(0,255), 200);
  ellipse(mouseX, mouseY, random(10,50), random(10,50));
}

void mouseClicked()
{
  setup();
}
```

I get to export the HTML file but it doesn't work (unlike in Java mode):
[Image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/uDTY4.png)

Comment: Can you post the html you're using? Can you link us to a url with your sketch? What shows up in the JavaScript console? Why are you calling `setup()` from `mouseClicked()`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your best friend when developing with Processing.js is the **JavaScript console**. If you've developed with Processing before, the JavaScript console is like the black console section at the bottom of the Processing editor- it's where any errors or exceptions will go.

However, the JavaScript console is hidden by default. To open it, press `F12` (or look for a menu called "developer tools") in your browser, and then go to the `console` tab.

When you have that open, you can refresh your page to view any errors you're getting in you sketch.

Without being able to view the JavaScript console on a URL running your sketch, I can't really give you a more specific answer. But a lot of novice Processing.js developers aren't aware of the JavaScript console, so more often than not this ends up solving the problem.

Comment: @MatiasElpfjds Well, the error says it all: you're opening this as a file, but you need to open it as a URL on a local server. Processing will do this for you automatically if you press the play button in JavaScript mode, or you have to set up a local server, or you have to upload it to a web server. You can't just open the index file directly.